# RequireJs exporting Handlebars templates

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, handlebars.js

I'm trying to create a sort of template loader class in my js project, using backbone,requirejs and handlebars.

The objective is to dynamically load handlebars templates from the application and **NOT** from the config file, like

```
something.addTemplate('text!path/to/template','templateName');
```

Inside the class i have this:

```
    [...]
    addTemplate : function (path,name)
    {          
      //_templates is an array defined outside
      _templates[name] = require([path],function(tpl){
        result = Handlebars.compile(tpl);  //this is a Handlebar compiled template
        return result;
       });

      console.log(_templates[name]); // returns the js code of the require function (i think)                             
    },
    [...other stuff...]
```

so, at the end of the addTemplate function _templats[name] does **NOT** contain the compiled template...

can you help me?

**EDIT**

After getting some suggestion in the chat i update the question with more details:

what i'm trying to achieve is to compile handlebars templates only once, the first time they are called.

What i'd expect is to be able, somewhere in the code to do:
    templatemanager.addTemplate('path','name'); // load the file with requirejs, compiles it with handlebars and stores it in the template manager

and somewhere else, possibly in many places, to be able to do something like
    templatemanager.getTemplate('name');

that returns the compiled handlebars template.

I believe that due to the asynchronous nature of requirejs i have to "do something" on both the addtemplate and even the getTemplate using deferred objects and promises.

what's that something?

**EDIT 2**

i partially solved refactoring the functions. i write it here if someone else has the same problem:

```
addTemplate : function (path,name)
    {          
      var deferred = $.Deferred();

      require([path],function(tpl){
        _templates[name]  = Handlebars.compile(tpl);                                          
        deferred.resolve(_templates[name]);                      
      });

      return deferred.promise();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that require function is asynchronous. Its callback is executed after console.log.

You might want to use [promise](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

```
    addTemplate : function (path,name)
    {
      var deferred = $.Deferred();
      //_templates is an array defined outside
      _templates[name] = require([path],function(tpl){
        result = Handlebars.compile(tpl);  //this is a Handlebar compiled template
        //return result;
         deferred.resolve(result);
       });

      console.log(_templates[name]); // returns the js code of the require function (i think)
      return deferred.promise();
    },
```

**Loading single template**

```
addTemplate(path, name).then(function() {
   console.log('template added');
}
```

**Loading multiple templates**

var deferredArray = [];

```
for (...) {
   deferredArray.push(addTemplate(path, name));
}
$.when.apply($, deferredArray).then(function(result) {
   console.log('template added');
});
```

Comment: could you explain something more ? i can't understand a way to "merge" jquery Deferred/promises (for example) with my code.

also , the function passed as second parameter is fired when requirejs finishes the loading. 
but i cannot pass inside that function the _templates variable

Comment: @Stormsson You cannot pass your own parameters to require callback function, because you are not the one, who calls this callback. It is RqeuireJs who calls this callback and passes all parameters.

Comment: sadly it doesn't work :( i give you +1 anyway because you have clearly explained the problem, but i don't seem to be able to make it go (also i have no idea on how to tag you because you have a space in the name)